# Construct a 3D tensor from a 2D matrix

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytorch, tensor

Given an n-by-n matrix A, where each row of A is a permutation of [n], e.g.,

```py
import torch
n = 100
AA = torch.rand(n, n)
A = torch.argsort(AA, dim=1)
```

Also given another n-by-n matrix P, we want to construct a 3D tensor Q s.t.

```
Q[i, j, k] = P[A[i, j], k]
```

Is there any efficient way in pytorch?
I am aware of *torch.gather* but it seems hard to be directly applied here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can directly use:

```
Q = P[A]
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply use `A` as an index:

```py
Q = P[A, :]
```